# Logout user before deleting via parse cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

I am currently writing a background job that deletes a (for inappropriate content, or violation of the license agreement) flagged user and all his content.

The problem is that if the user doesn’t logout manually, he can still use the app (and even create new content) even if his account does not exist anymore.

So is there a way to logout a specific user via cloud code or destroy his session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content creation in your Parse app isn't limited to a logged in and valid user by default, Parse does not know that you might want to limit content creation to valid and logged in users or not, some developers might even not use user accounts at all etc.

It is up to you to ensure that the client/user making the request is allowed to do so. This can either be enforced by using an ACL on your classes or by using a beforeSave function in Cloud Code. I prefer Cloud Code and it is pretty straight forward to enforce a valid user there.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("YourClass", function(request,response) {
    if (request.user == null) {
        response.error();
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you. This makes much sense. I have one other problem, that my afterDelete function for User is not executed when I delete a User with my Backgroundjob. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Deleting a user requires the master key, if you don't use it yet, add this to your background job 'Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();'. If you are already doing this and it still does not work I suggest you file a bug at parse.com/help

Comment: Figured it out: it had to be Parse.Cloud.afterDelete(Parse.User… not Parse.Cloud.afterDelete(“User”